# How to define recursive type alias in Rust?

Tags: rust

So in Rust, I can define recursive type using enum like this:

```
enum Trie {
    Child(HashMap<char, Box<Trie>>)
}
```

However this is a little bit verbose, considering that this enum has only one member.

May I know how to make it simpler? Let's say using type alias like this?

```
// This code does not compile in rustc 1.55.0
type Trie = HashMap<char, Box<Trie>>;
```

Comment: The problem with `type` is it is just an *alias*, so the actual type it reflects is `HashMap<char, Box<HashMap<char, Box<HashMap<char, ...` ad infinitum, which Rust cannot express. You need a concrete type like a `struct` in Makalone's answer to remove that recursion from the type definition itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a single field struct compiles:

```rust
struct Trie(HashMap<char, Box<Trie>>);
```

Comment: It can even be simplified: `struct Trie(HashMap<char, Trie>)`; `Box` is not needed here thanks to `HashMap`